# Django Debug Toolbar shows up, but links are broken

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

The relevant settings in my settings.py are as follows

```
DEBUG = True
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False
INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...,
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    ...,
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'debug_toolbar',
    ...,
)
```

I also have the urls.py file set up as per the [explicit setup instructions](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#explicit-setup). The toolbar does show up, but doesn't appear as it should. There are checkboxes next to each menu item and all the links have href="#".

[image: DjDb Toolbar Glitch]

This seems strange - I've used DjDb before but I've never seen this. If anyone can provide some insight into this problem that would be great! Thanks

UPDATE:

As pointed out by Alasdair, the checkboxes are a new feature, and the links are directed by the javascript component of django-debug-toolbar, so they properly have href="#". Opening the browser's JS console did show that the toolbar is using a deprecated property:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

But this is just a warning, so I would expect it to still work regardless.

Comment: I'm using djang-debug-toolbar 0.11.0.

Comment: Make sure to check if the docs you read are the same that come with the version you use (you can check in the Github repo) - I was using somehow a later version than what the docs where for and then discovered different install instructions on Github.

Answer (score 2):

All the links are meant to be `href="#"`. The checkboxes are a recent addition to allow you to disable panels.

It sounds like the JavaScript isn't working for you. Use the developer tools of your browser to look for errors, perhaps 404s or JavaScript errors.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair - this clears up a bit of my confusion. I didn't notice I was using a newer version of django-debug-toolbar. I should've checked the version and change logs.

Comment: I have one other suggestion, since there aren't any errors in the console. Do a full refresh, to make sure that your browser isn't caching the js file from an earlier version of the toolbar. Hope you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I had trouble like the OP's.  Looks like it was javascript cached from an older version of the toolbar, so clearing the browser cache solved it.  Thanks Alasdair!